# sed to replace multiple pairs of identical pattern on same line

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace the file `test.txt` containing

```
some text $\alpha$ some text $\alpha$ some text
some text $\beta$ some text
some text $\gamma$.
some text $\delta$
$\epsilon$ some text $\epsilon$
$\mu$

some text `$a$` some text `$a$` some text
some text `$b$` some text
some text `$c$`.
some text `$d$`
`$e$` some text `$e$`
`$f$`

$$\Alpha$$
    $$\Beta$$

`$$A$$`
    `$$B$$`
```

by

```
some text '$\alpha$' some text `$\alpha$` some text
some text '$\beta$' some text
some text '$\gamma$'.
some text '$\delta$'
`$\epsilon$` some text `$\epsilon$`
`$\mu$`

some text `$a$` some text
some text `$b$` some text
some text `$c$`. 
some text `$d$`
`$e$` some text `$e$`
`$m$`

`$$\Alpha$$`
    `$$\Beta$$`

`$$A$$`
    `$$B$$`
```

In short, I want to do the replacements

```
$..$ --> `$..$`
```

and

```
$$..$$ --> `$$..$$`
```

in one set of of `sed` commands. But if the set of commands is reapplied on the file is should not add extra (`) symbols.

So far I have tried the following set:

```
    sed -e 's/^\(\$\$.*\$\$\)/`\1`/g' -i test.txt
    sed -e 's/[^`]\(\$\$[^`].*[^\$]\$\$\)[^`]/`\1`/g' -i test.txt
    sed -e 's/^\(\$.[^\$]*\$\)/`\1`/g' -i test.txt
    sed -e 's/[^`$$]\(\$[^`].[^\$]*\$\)[^`$$]/ `\1` /g' -i test.txt
```

but this doesnt work fully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get off with a single `sed` expression:

```
# ERE
sed -E 's/([^`$]|^)(\${1,2}[^`$]+\${1,2})([^`$]|$)/\1`\2`\3/g' test.txt

# or, if you prefer BRE (but only with GNU sed)
sed 's/\([^`$]\|^\)\(\$\{1,2\}[^`$]\+\$\{1,2\}\)\([^`$]\|$\)/\1`\2`\3/g' test.txt
```

gives you:

```
some text `$\alpha$` some text `$\alpha$` some text
some text `$\beta$` some text
some text `$\gamma$`.
some text `$\delta$`
`$\epsilon$` some text `$\epsilon$`
`$\mu$`

some text `$a$` some text `$a$` some text
some text `$b$` some text
some text `$c$`.
some text `$d$`
`$e$` some text `$e$`
`$f$`

`$$\Alpha$$`
    `$$\Beta$$`

`$$A$$`
    `$$B$$`
```

We match three groups:

- prefix: a single non-backtick or non-dollar or line beginning
- the meat: one or two `$`, followed by content, followed by one/two `$`
- suffix: same as prefix, except we match line ending

then print them out, quoting with backticks only the middle group. We need to anchor on those prefix and suffix to avoid that double quoting you're experiencing.

**Note** that the POSIX BRE (basic regular expression) form above uses several GNU extensions, namely: anchoring on line beginning and line ending used in the middle of expression (and not as the first/last character in pattern), alternation (`\|`) and one-or-more duplication operator (`\+`). If you need this expression to work in POSIX BRE, you'll need to break it into several (i.e. 3) subexpressions and use `\{1,\}` instead of `\+`.

But also note that the POSIX ERE (extended regular expressions) form given should work in all modern `sed` environments, on both GNU and BSD systems.

Comment: Hmm.. I can't reproduce that. Can you narrow the input for which it doesn't work? Because for the sample from your question it seems to work.

Comment: yes it adds the (`) but the "." disappears (for the line 4 of the file, the one with delta)

Comment: There was no `.` after `delta` in the input file. It works for `gamma` which is followed by a dot.

Comment: That would fail if the input can contain `$$foo$bar$$`, i.e. a single `$` between a matched pair of `$$`s. idk if that's possible or not....

Comment: @EdMorton, good catch, thanks. I'm curious is that a valid var name/syntax, though. @ PinkFloyd ?

Comment: @EdMorton you are right but I don't expect to have this... but i found another case where it fails (not in my `test.txt` file example, sorry, edited) : if the line starts with `$\alpha$ some text $\beta$`. This case would need to be solved... can you?

Comment: @PinkFloyd, are you referring to the `'$e$'` you added (because it's working for `$e$` and `\`$e$\``)? That isn't handled because you used single-quotes instead of backticks. Should the script support single-quotes (alongside `\``)?

Comment: another case it'd fail is `$\alpha$$\beta$`, i.e. no text between the 2 `$..$` sets.

Comment: I had an issue when translating in vim... but I think its okay !

Comment: @PinkFloyd, the BRE form I posted uses GNU extensions (`^` not at the beginning, `$` not at the end, and `|`), but ERE form should work for all your cases. Can you verify it does?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `perl` then it much more easier using lookaround regex (that are not supported in sed regex):

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!`)(\$++[^\s\$]*\$++)(?!`)/`$1`/g' file

some text `$\alpha$` some text `$\alpha$` some text
some text `$\beta$` some text
some text `$\gamma$`.
some text `$\delta$`
`$\epsilon$` some text
`$\mu$`

some text `$a$` some text `$a$` some text
some text `$b$` some text
some text `$c$`.
some text `$d$`
`$e$` some text
`$f$`

`$$\Alpha$$`
    `$$\Beta$$`

`$$A$$`
    `$$B$$`
```

To save changes back to file use:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<!`)(\$++[^\s\$]*\$++)(?!`)/`$1`/g' file
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yNoLEj/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?<!`) - Negative Lookbehind to assert previous character is not `
( - Star captured group #1
   \$++ - Match one or more $
   [^\s\$]* - Match zero or more non-whitespace non-$ characters
   \$++ - Match one or more $
) - End captured group #1
(?!`) - Negative Lookahead to assert next character is not `
```